# Setting interval only once by an event listener, but run other functions every time

Tags: javascript, function, events, setinterval, event-listener

See this code:

```
function handleTouchStart(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       cnvs.removeEventListener("touchstart", handleTouchStart);
       var x1 = event.touches[0].clientX-cnvs.offsetLeft;
       callerOfCNVSTouchStart = setInterval(function () {
         if (x1 > cnvs.width/2  && whiteShip.x2 < cnvs.width) {
          whiteShip.x1+= 3;
         } else if (x1 < cnvs.width/2 && whiteShip.x1 > 0) {
          whiteShip.x1-= 3;
         }
        }, 20);
        nBMC = setInterval(makeNewBullets,200);
        setInterval(sendEnemies,2000);//I want to run this line only once 
}
```

I want the other functions to run every time the event occurs, but set the interval for `sendEnemies` only once. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable like `var sentEnemies = false;` outside function `handleTouchStart` and update it in the function to `true` the first time and use `if(!sentEnemies)` for the line to execute only once.

```
var sentEnemies = false;

function handleTouchStart(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       cnvs.removeEventListener("touchstart", handleTouchStart);
       var x1 = event.touches[0].clientX-cnvs.offsetLeft;
       callerOfCNVSTouchStart = setInterval(function () {
         if (x1 > cnvs.width/2  && whiteShip.x2 < cnvs.width) {
          whiteShip.x1+= 3;
         } else if (x1 < cnvs.width/2 && whiteShip.x1 > 0) {
          whiteShip.x1-= 3;
         }
        }, 20);
        nBMC = setInterval(makeNewBullets,200);

        if (!sentEnemies) {
           setInterval(sendEnemies,2000); // Will execute only once
           sentEnemies = true;
        }
        
}
```

Comment: I am asking about a function... Isn't there a short way(single line code) to achieve this?

Comment: I mean you can assign the interval to an external variable and check if it is already there but other than that I don't think there is a single line code since you have to maintain an external state outside `handleTouchStart` to check if it is the first time or not.

Comment: I just don't want to create extra unnecessary global variables... I should look up for some other way. Thanks for your time!

Comment: If global variables is the issue you can use [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to solve it. If you want I can edit the above solution to use closures

Comment: No thanks... I want to make the code simple. I will think of another way.